# Close mysql connection through shell script

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I am running shell scripts which have multiple mysql -u <> -e "select * from tbl" statements. Do i need to explicitly close mysql connection through my shell script? If yes, can you guide me on how to do that?

I am seeing many sleep connections in mysql. Even if i kill them, they are created again in short period an i am suspecting that shell script execution is causing this.

Thanks

Comment: As per mysql --help, the -e flag executes the query and QUITS.   "-e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history
                      file.)". I dont think it is because of the shell script. You may be seeing sleep connections on mysql based on your mysql configuration, with a minimum open Connection Pool Size.

Comment: Thank you for the update. i will try to debug it from this front as well

Comment: Exiting a process releases all its TCP connections at the TCP level. The 'sleep' connections you are seeing are unrelated.

Answer (score -1):

If you didn't solve the root cause of the sleep queries it will be restarted and will consume the resources after each time you killed the connection, so you have to check your code and modify it to close the connection after executing the query.

Any way, you can kill any connection by it's ID which can be determined by:

`mysql -e 'show processlist;'`

The ID will be in the first column and then you can kill them by the following:

`mysql -e 'kill $ID'`

And to kill them all in one time:

`for i in $(mysql -e "show processlist" | awk '/Sleep/ {print $1}'); do mysql -e "KILL $i;"; done`